# How to replace the first two digits with one digit Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

I'd like to replace the first two digit and replace it with 0
In case it start with 0 then nothing need to be changed. 
Example: **44**5656 to **0**56....

```
<cfif number (BEGIN WITH?) "44">
<cfset number = Right(number , Len(number )-2) />
```

But this just will remove the first two digits. thank you for the support

Comment: *the first two digit* Did you try the `left()` function?

Comment: What if it starts with something other than `0` or `44`?

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion?

Comment: @James, version ColdFusion 9
@ David, it start always with 44 i want to replace it with 0

Comment: What if the number is 4405656, should it become 005656 or 05656? Should the final value be a fixed number of positions?

Comment: @Stef A word of caution, just because it currently starts with 0 or 44, doesn't necessarily mean that it will "always" be so. I can't tell you how many times I've had to refactor something because business requirements changed way down the road. And if it's trivial to account for a base rule at the beginning, you may as well use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're keeping your numbers that "*start with 0*" as strings. Try this:

```
<!--- // a number that does not start with zero --->
<cfset theNumber = "445656" />
<cfset theNumber = left(theNumber, 1) is 0 ? theNumber : REReplaceNoCase(theNumber, "^[0-9]{2}", 0) />
<!--- // returns 05656 --->
<cfoutput>#theNumber#</cfoutput>

<hr />

<!--- // a number that starts with zero --->
<cfset theNumber = "05656" />
<cfset theNumber = left(theNumber, 1) is 0 ? theNumber : REReplaceNoCase(theNumber, "^[0-9]{2}", 0) />
<!--- // returns 05656 --->
<cfoutput>#theNumber#</cfoutput>
```

If your number always starts with either 0 or 44 you can use

```
<cfset theNumber = left(theNumber, 1) is 0 
                    ? theNumber 
                    : REReplaceNoCase(theNumber, "^[4]{2}", 0) />
```

> Update:
>   Also, read the comments, there are some good points in there.

Comment: HI Alex, thank you. In this case only if the number is equal 445656 the change will happen. what if it start with 44777 or 44325? the 44 will always be in the beginning. thx. for the support

Comment: If your number always starts with either 0 or 44 you can use `REReplaceNoCase(theNumber, "^[4]{2}", 0)` It will work with any number that starts with 44 including 44777 or 44325

Comment: Just a nitpick, but `left(theNumber),1 is 0` is implicitly converting a string to a number. I'd go with `"0"`. Same in the replace value. It would make you nuts to debug an issue if it unintentionally set the new value to a number instead of a string and truncated the 0 off the front. EDIT NOTE: `REReplaceNoCase()` returns a string, so wouldn't likely typecast the end result back to a number. But it still will have to typecast the replace value. Micro-optimization, but still may as well write it in the first place.

Comment: And also just to be on the side of code clarity, I probably wouldn't call it `theNumber` but `the[WhateverTheHeckThisStringRelatesTo]`.

Comment: You don't need `REReplaceNoCase()` (there are no letters involved in the pattern); you can just use `REReplace("^44", theNumber, "0")`

Comment: @DavidFaber - Interesting. Didn't realize you can jusst use REReplaceNoCase() without the ternary stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This reReplace() can be run on any string, will only modify and replace with 0 if the string starts with 44.

```
<cfscript>
   phoneNumber = "44556677";
   phoneNumber = reReplace(phoneNumber, "^44", "0");
   writeOutput(phoneNumber);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Change the regex `^44` to `^[1-9][0-9]` to replace any two digits that do not start with `0`.